# eclipse error "failed to get tags" in Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

In my project I have an error in run time: `failed to get tags 4/15`,although it works without "ANR" dialog.But **some times** in project main activity,when it becomes visible,background changes and an icon's background becomes activity's background.I checked my code,every things is in it's place and when I debug project,background name is true,even when it's background is wrong.Really I am not sure that this problem is in about that error,but when I try debugging,only this error is appearing in LogCat.
How I can solve this problem?I use `eclipse`.

Comment: Do you try for clean/builde your project?

Comment: @hasanghaforian yes I try this and try to close and re open eclipse,delete `gen` and so on,but my problem exists.

Comment: Post some code. From your question, we can't see what you are doing (how you set the background etc.).